# What's wrong with this MySQL query? (Trying to re-add leading 0's to zip codes)

Tags: mysql, zipcode

I have a table of zip codes, and alot of fields in it lost their leading zero's during import. I have a query that should re-add the zeros to the left and I've run this query with no errors, however it says 0 rows were affected:

```
UPDATE `Zip Codes` SET Code = right(concat("00000",Code), 5) WHERE length(Code) < 5;
```

Anyone able to see what the problem might be?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to execute on the console?

Comment: How did you define the column 'Code', int? or char?

Comment: Are you storing them as VARCHAR? How are you actually validating that the zeroes are missing? For example, exporting to Excel can drop leading zeros (problem I've had many times). I'm guessing you stored as INT and that's why there were dropped. Use VARCHAR.

Comment: Aha! I had it defind as int(5). Switching to varchar(5) fixed it. Thanks!

Madmartigan, I'd mark your answer as the accepted answer, but I dont' see how to for a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zip codes, like telephone numbers, should always be stored as `VARCHAR` an not `INT`.

Why?

They aren't integers, and don't represent actual numbers. You aren't really sorting them, you aren't incrementing them or adding them together, they don't represent an amount of something, they are merely codes - and can theoretically contain any character including alphas and punctuation.

If they were integers, then `00123` would mean exactly the same as `123`.

For example, check out the [Wikipedia page on Zip Code Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code#Formats), there are many varieties of format and length. Even in the U.S., there are extensions that will make them be more than the 5 digits you've alotted.

`VARCHAR(32)` should be adequate.

Comment: In your application logic, I would still advise some attempt at enforced integrity, whether it be formatting or checking against a known database of zip codes.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in this particular app I'm only going to be needing to pull the zip codes out and their accuracy isn't even particularly important. There will also be no more additions to the list so I'm most likely going to leave it at 5 in this circumstance. =)

Comment: While not the same thing, I learned a hard lesson once when I stored all-numeric account numbers as INT. In my PHP code, I was casting to integer and some account numbers hit the ceiling and several dupes appeared as 2147483647, like this: http://codepad.org/9shZ1yC8 Not the same thing, just a similar story of failure I wanted to share. We had to bluff hardware failure to save face.

Answer (score 0):

What error does this produce?

```
SELECT right(concat("00000",Code), 5) FROM `Zip Codes` WHERE length(Code) < 5;
```

That basically what the update is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the number or column and click "Format cells" -> Special -> Zip codes.   In other cases where you want leading zeros you could do  "Format cells" -> Custom.  From there, there're numerous options you can select.